# processing LZO sequence files with mrjob

Tags: python, hadoop, lzo, mrjob

I'm writing a task with [mrjob](http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/) to compute various statistics using the Google Ngrams data: https://aws.amazon.com/datasets/8172056142375670

I developed & tested my script locally using an uncompressed subset of the data in tab-delimited text. Once I tried to run the job, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ngram_counts.py", line 74, in <module>
    MRNGramCounts.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 500, in run
    mr_job.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 509, in execute
    self.run_mapper(self.options.step_num)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 574, in run_mapper
    for out_key, out_value in mapper(key, value) or ():
  File "ngram_counts.py", line 51, in mapper
    (ngram, year, _mc, _pc, _vc) = line.split('\t')
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
(while reading from s3://datasets.elasticmapreduce/ngrams/books/20090715/eng-1M/5gram/data)
```

Presumably this is because of the public data set's compression scheme (from the URL link above):

> We store the datasets in a single object in Amazon S3. The file is in
>   sequence file format with block level LZO compression. The sequence
>   file key is the row number of the dataset stored as a LongWritable and
>   the value is the raw data stored as TextWritable.

Any guidance on how to set up a workflow that can process these files? I've searched exhaustively for tips but haven't turned up anything useful...

(I'm a relative n00b to mrjob and Hadoop.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out. It looks like EMR takes care of the LZO compression for you, but for the sequence file format, you need to add the following HADOOP_INPUT_FORMAT field to your MRJob class:

```
class MyMRJob(MRJob):

    HADOOP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat'

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        # mapper code...

    def reducer(self, key, value):
        # reducer code...
```

There's another gotcha, too (quoting from the AWS-hosted Google NGrams page):

> The sequence file key is the row number of the dataset stored as a LongWritable and the value is the raw data stored as TextWritable.

That means each row is prepended with and extra Long + TAB, so any line parsing you do in your mapper method needs to account for the prepended info as well.